# CSS hover change another div (within another seperate wrapper div)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to alter another div element with css hover. I got it working when they are under the same container. But on my site the element that has to be changed has to be under another separate wrapper div.

HTML

```
<div class="a">Div A</div>
<div id="box">
    <div class="c">Div C</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.a:hover ~ .c {
    background: #3F6;
}

#box {
}
```

Here's what I want to achieve... works in the first set when you hover over Div A. Does not on the second set.
https://jsfiddle.net/69017jwc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example, `.c` isn't a sibling of the `.a` element.

You would need to select the sibling `#box` element and then select the descendant `.c` element from there, `.a:hover ~ #box .c`:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/aLxe0yzd/)

```
.a:hover ~ .c,
.a:hover ~ #box .c {
    background: #3F6;
}
```

If the element that contains the `.c` element doesn't have a class or an id, then you could just use the universal selector:

```
.a:hover ~ * .c {
    background: #3F6;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I have multiple elements within #box that I want to target but I figured out.

https://jsfiddle.net/7o2y027u/

Answer (score 0):

Im not too sure what you are looking to do but from what I understand you want it to highlight each different "question" sepertly. If so try this:

```
<div>
<div class="a">Div A</div>
<div class="b">Div B</div>
<div class="c">Div C</div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="a">Div A</div>
<div class="b">Div B</div>
<div class="c">Div C</div>
```